# Unable create paypal payment for float amount

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I am trying to create direct payment with paypal rest api (by using credit card ID) for amount 19.50 but failed. I got following error:

> Exception: Got Http response code 400 when accessing
>   https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.

```
{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"transactions[0].item_list.items[0].price","issue":"Currency amount must be non-negative number, may optionally contain exactly 2 decimal places separated by '.', optional thousands separator ',', limited to 7 digits before the decimal point"}
```

I am wonder that all round amount like 10.00, 15.00 etc work fine. Here is my example code:

http://pastebin.com/2NQSn3aW

I have tried some random float amount like 2.5, 3.5 etc and all time got same error. Is this paypal restriction that float amount can not be use?

I am using sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be using the new SDK.

I found no error using the SDK version provided by Paypal. I have used

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php" : "0.5.*"
}
```

You can check the code [here](http://pastebin.com/VyY8GC68)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, it make sense to me. I can't test right now, I will back with my test result after try out.

Comment: It seams to me, its a temporary internal problem with Paypal. As currently I am unable to do **Payment with saved credit card** using none of the SDK version.

Answer (score 2):

> Currency amount must be non-negative number, may optionally contain exactly 2 decimal places separated by '.',

because you are placing the initial amount 0.0 rather 0.00 format. It is recommended to currency amount must contain **exactly 2 decimal places separated by '.',**

Comment: you asked in your question about the currency restrictions, so i give you the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

had the same issue so used this

```
$amount = 16.86;    
$formattedAmount = number_format($amount,2);
```

and it worked !

Answer (score 1):

Definitely an issue with PayPal sandbox. I'm using version 2.1.1 of their iOS SDK. It's impossible to have an item for $5.00.  It would have to be $4.99 or $5.01.

Answer (score 0):

As it says here

> Currency amount must be non-negative number, may optionally contain **exactly 2 decimal places** separated by '.',

So it should contain 2 decimal places, or no decimal places.

You can enforce 2 decimal places in php like this:

```
 <?php
 $numWithTwoDecimalPlaces = sprintf("%0.2f", $number);
```

[See Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/849b216a9a1d2b96863bbe728aa7f11993651474)

Comment: Thank for response but your example not working. it should be "%0.2f" instead of "%0.2d", which I have already tried. Please see my given example.

Answer (score 0):

I have figure out the problem (temporary) is in Paypal sandbox API. This problem occur only for sandbox API when trying to create payment by card id (vault).

Thanks for every one for your time.